# Как корректно переносить сторки в html страницу сайта с админ панели Djnago

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

В некой модели , допустим , `Main_model` есть поле `Text_filed`.Редакция содержимого этого поля может осуществятся только в админ панели Django.На этом этапе возникает проблема.В html странице нет отступов , заданных в админ панели.Вопрос , как эти модели туда перенести?

```
пример :
#DJANGO АДМИН ПАНЕЛЬ
Это какой-то текст 
Это перенос на следующую строку

#HTML страница
Это какой-то текст Это перенос на следующую строку
```

Answer (score 0):

Хоть и небыло дано ответа , я все же  разобрался. Я добавил атрибут `linebreaks` в `{{some_object.TEXT_FIELD_NAME|linebreaks}}` и все переносы сохранились.Как я понимаю , `linebreaks`  разпознает `'/n'`  и все , проблема исчерпана!